Pop ups on Macbook dock when wife is on her iPhone! i.e Chrome browser with an iPhone icon in corner
What is this all about, yeah we have a shared email we use for apple stuff, but that doesn't mean I want to invade her privacy or vice versa. How can I stop this behaviour? When this first started happening I lost all the icons/launchers off my macbook doc. Any insight welcome!

Do you both have separate AppleID to enter in the main iCloud preferences? You can always go in and share one email by adding that as a second account in mail app. https://support.apple.com/en-us/109040

That is Apple's "Handoff" feature. It suggests your activities on another device to make it easier to continue your activity on this device.
You can turn it off in settings. Or just don't use the same Apple ID on devices that will be used by different people.

Thanks, sorted!

@MatthewTompkins If this answer solved your problem you should consider marking it as the accepted answer
